# iOS 64-bit support for unity integrated application

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ios8, 64-bit, il2cpp

Since 1st of February 2015 Appstore ask for the  64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. We had integrated our iOS app  with unity and works fine. Currently we are using 32-bit version of unity and we use asset bundles which built from it in our iOS app. 
According to new regulations we have to change "Architectures" in iOS app to “**Standard architectures (armv7, arm64)**”. It doesn't support unity parts in the application. As a solution unity suggest to select **IL2CPP** for  **Scripting** **Backend** which is available from **Unity 4.6.2** . 
Is there any solution instead of upgrading Unity to latest version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll definitely need to upgrade to a Unity version that supports `IL2CPP`, as this is the only option to create an `ARM64` build.

But you won't need the latest version (e.g. 5.x) of Unity for that, as you already pointed out, 4.6.2 would be sufficient.

**But I'd recommend at least to stick to the latest 4.6.x version, as there are tons of bugfixes from 4.6.2 to that version related to IL2CPP**

Comment: Note that all of the IL2CPP bug fixes are in all versions of Unity, 4.6 and 5.1.

Comment: There are definitley not all bug fixes in e.g. 4.6.2.. so you should got with the latest 4.6 or latest 5.x versions of unity.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misunderstood that part initially. Your answer is correct.

Comment: thanks guys. I had upgraded to 5.1.1 and it seems to like some of the Standard Assets from Unity4 not working in Unity5. Ex : **Type `UnityEngine.Mesh' does not contain a definition for `SetTriangleStrip' and no extension method `SetTriangleStrip' of type `UnityEngine.Mesh' could be found**

Comment: There are some, afaik also breaking, changes from 4.6 to 5. Did you try the latest 4.6.x version? It should have all the IL2CPP fixes, while still being a 4.6 version, without those breaking changes.